# If I run an infected file on VMware does my main OS gets infected as well?

Tags: windows-7, linux, vmware, virus

If it does or could potentially happen what about if I have linux (as an alternative installed native OS) and run VMware in linux to run a windows virtual machine and run it in there?

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible.

Newer versions of VMWare allow access between the host and guest disks and in that situation you could have a virus jump outside the VM. If you've got something that spreads to networked machines then you could be at risk that way as well.

Your best bet for isolation would be to disable any disk sharing and run the guest without any network connectivity.

Comment: I see. What about if I wanna use it even though it might be backdoored and requires internet connection?

Comment: Then just as with another physical box sitting there, your network is at risk.

Answer (score 0):

Like so many things, the answer is it depends.

By default, no. They are segregated and do not communicate directly. If you share resources like a hard drive share (Not the virtual drives in the VM) or have it sitting on your network via a networking (Not using bridge or NAT alone).

So, in short if you share drives or network it then it acts like any other two machines that use a share or sit on the same network. Otherwise its safe.